# UICollectionView items flow direction vertical and scroll with horizontal direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, layout, uicollectionview

i have UICollectionView, i need Horizontal scroll direction and Vertical items flow. It's possible with native instruments?

Comment: can you please provide more details about the layout, with images for reference?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40173261/3807336

Answer (score 0):

You can have a *parent* UICollectionView scrolling vertically & each section or row can contain *child* CollectionViews scrolling vertically.
To maintain sanity, do setup your `dataSource`'s for parent & child's independent of each other.
You should be able to utilise same handler for all *child* collectionViews.

Answer (score 0):

You have add UITableView inside that tableviewcell add the UICollectionView and also set the UICollectionView Scroll Direction is Horizontal.