# Nested collectionView in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've been successfully nesting collections views into tableview for a while now.

What I still don't know how to do, is to do it while respecting the MVC pattern?

Right now I declare my tableview and its cells and in the cell (where the collectionView sits), I attach my collectionView (I got 1 per cell) and do the data mapping. It works, but it's spaghetti code where my View is acting like a controller.

I tried a few times to respect the MVC patterns. I can get my controller to control both my tableview and my collection. Where I struggle is to tell my collection View delegate which data it should pick as all I have as reference is the indexPath (of the collectionView) but not in which tableView that specific collectionView sits.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

The delegate only gives me the indexPath of the cell not which collectionView it is. To use a concrete example - let's assume that my tableview cells represents messages and that each message has a collectionView that controls reactions (like Discord). How do I tell my collectionView delegate which Message it is linked to?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Every view and its subclass has a property `tag`. You must have an `IBOutlet` or a simple reference to the `CollectionView` that sits in the `TableViewCell`. When you dequeue the `TableViewCell` just set the tag of your `CollectionView` equal to the `indexPath.row` of your `tableViewCell` like this:

```
tableViewCell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in the `UICollectionViewDataSource` or `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods you may find which collectionView it is in other words which tableViewCell does this collectionView sits in. Here's an example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let dataObject = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row] as! YourDataModelObject

    // Here you may set any property of the collectionView cell
    return cell
}
```

**P.S:** It is not necessary to respect MVC to that extent. You may manage your CollectionView from the TableViewCell. Have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173261/3807336).