# How to display content using collection view inside a Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi All!

I am trying to display some content using a collectionView inside a table view, but when I run the application the tableview is still empty and no content is getting display on the collection view. I have set the datasource and the delegate to the collection view.  I am wondering how can I fix and what am I doing wrong.Thanks for all replies.

[image: Table view image]

````
Tableviewcell 
```
class DiscoverTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {


 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionviewOutlet.delegate = self
        collectionviewOutlet.dataSource = self

        collectionviewOutlet.reloadData()
    }


   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
//enter image description here
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return businesses.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellColl", for: indexPath) as! DiscoverCollectionViewCell
        let business = businesses\[indexPath.row\]
        cell.restaurantName.text = business.name
        cell.restaurantPrice.text = business.price
        return cell
    }
}
```

//Tableview controller 
```
class DiscoverRestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DiscoverTableViewCell {
//     

      return cell
        }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }
}
```
//CollectionView cell 
```
class DiscoverCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var restaurantImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var restaurantName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var restaurantPrice: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!


}

```
````

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173261/3807336) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set dataSource of tableView like

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

And try to reload data in tableView like

```
tableView.reloadData()
```