# parsing complex JSON to UITableView And UICollectionView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i am creating swift app and i want to parse `JSON` but first let me show you my `UI`

i have One `UITableview` inside tableview cell i have `UICollectionView` and below is the screen shot of my `UserInterface`

[image: Please Check UI below]

And here is my `JSON` which i have to parse

```
{
  "jigyasa_category_list": [
    {
      "status": "1",
      "updated_date": "2019-11-18 17:02:37",
      "created_date": "2019-08-28 16:32:22",
      "jigyasa_category_image_id": "4",
      "jigyasa_sanskrit": "jigyasa cate sanskrit 2",
      "jig_cate_id": "7",
      "jigyasa": [
        {
          "image1": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_1.png",
          "name_english": "",
          "image5": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_5.png",
          "name_sanskrit": "",
          "images": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_1.png",
          "image2": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_2.png",
          "name_hindi": "gfdgfd",
          "image4": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_4.png",
          "image3": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/purple_3.png",
          "jigyasa_id": "8"
        }
      ],
      "updated_by": "2",
      "created_by": "2",
      "jigyasa_hindi": "jigyasa cate hindi 1",
      "jigyasa_english": "jigyasa cate english 3"
    },
    {
      "status": "1",
      "updated_date": "2019-11-13 16:28:43",
      "created_date": "2019-08-29 15:07:53",
      "jigyasa_category_image_id": "2",
      "jigyasa_sanskrit": "dfgh",
      "jig_cate_id": "11",
      "jigyasa": [
        {
          "image3": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_3.png",
          "jigyasa_id": "5",
          "image5": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_5.png",
          "name_sanskrit": "n,n,",
          "name_english": "n,n,",
          "images": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_1.png",
          "image2": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_2.png",
          "image1": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_1.png",
          "image4": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_4.png",
          "name_hindi": "n,n,"
        },
        {
          "image3": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_3.png",
          "jigyasa_id": "7",
          "image5": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_5.png",
          "name_sanskrit": "",
          "name_english": "",
          "images": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_2.png",
          "image2": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_2.png",
          "image1": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_1.png",
          "image4": "http:\/\/192.168.1.115\/swadhyay\/assets\/uploads\/jigyasa_category_boxes\/green_4.png",
          "name_hindi": "sadsa"
        }
      ],
      "updated_by": "0",
      "created_by": "2",
      "jigyasa_hindi": "fcgh",
      "jigyasa_english": "dfh"
    },
    {
      "created_date": "2019-10-11 17:07:09",
      "updated_date": "2019-10-11 17:10:04",
      "jigyasa_hindi": "hindi",
      "jig_cate_id": "14",
      "jigyasa_english": "english",
      "created_by": "2",
      "jigyasa_category_image_id": "2",
      "updated_by": "2",
      "status": "1",
      "jigyasa_sanskrit": "sanskrit",
      "jigyasa": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "created_date": "2019-11-04 10:48:06",
      "updated_date": "2019-11-04 10:48:06",
      "jigyasa_hindi": "hfgh",
      "jig_cate_id": "15",
      "jigyasa_english": "fghfg",
      "created_by": "2",
      "jigyasa_category_image_id": "2",
      "updated_by": "0",
      "status": "1",
      "jigyasa_sanskrit": "gfhfgh",
      "jigyasa": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "Jigyasa Category",
  "success": "1"
}
```

now i will show you what i have done to achieve this but not work for me

So for that i have create Model Class Like below

```
struct Jigyasa_category_list : Codable {
    let jigyasa_english : String?
    let jigyasa_hindi : String?
    let jigyasa_sanskrit : String?
    let jigyasa : [Jigyasa]?

    init(jigyasa_english: String?,jigyasa_hindi: String?,jigyasa_sanskrit: String,jigyasa: [Jigyasa]?) {
        self.jigyasa_english = jigyasa_english
        self.jigyasa_hindi = jigyasa_hindi
        self.jigyasa_sanskrit = jigyasa_sanskrit
        self.jigyasa = jigyasa
    }
}

struct Jigyasa : Codable {
    let image3 : String?
    let image1 : String?
    let name_english : String?
    let images : String?
    let name_hindi : String?
    let jigyasa_id : String?
    let image5 : String?
    let image4 : String?
    let name_sanskrit : String?
    let image2 : String?

    init(image3: String?,image1: String?,name_english: String,images: String?,name_hindi: String?,jigyasa_id: String?,image5: String?,image4: String?,name_sanskrit: String?,image2: String?) {
        self.image3 = image3
        self.image1 = image1
        self.name_english = name_english
        self.images = images
        self.name_hindi = name_hindi
        self.jigyasa_id = jigyasa_id
        self.image5 = image5
        self.image4 = image4
        self.name_sanskrit = name_sanskrit
        self.image2 = image2
    }
}
```

Now Collection view is in tableview cell so i have call api in UITableview Cell like below

```
var jigyasaData = [Jigyasa_category_list]()
func jigyasaCatList(){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let uid = "u_id"
        let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

        let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
        let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

        let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!]
        print(params)
        Alamofire.request(apijigyasacategorylist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let value):
                let json  = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                let data = json["jigyasa_category_list"]
                if data == []{

                }else{
                    data.array?.forEach({ (jList) in
                        let j_list = Jigyasa_category_list(jigyasa_english: jList["jigyasa_english"].stringValue, jigyasa_hindi: jList["jigyasa_hindi"].stringValue, jigyasa_sanskrit: jList["jigyasa_sanskrit"].stringValue, jigyasa: jList["jigyasa"].arrayObject as? [Jigyasa])
                        self.jigyasaData.append(j_list)
                    })
                }
                self.collView.reloadData()
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

but not understand how to parse in collection view which is inside `jigyasa`  array which is in JSON can any one please tell me how parse inside array data to collectionview

i just mean that i want to display data in collectionview from jigyasa array from json

Comment: Do you use ***SwiftyJSON*** to parse JSON data?

Comment: Yes i used `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/ past your json

Comment: and see you miss struct Welcom

Comment: even you don't need any library for parsing (SwiftyJSON)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am going to parse your JSON using **SwiftyJSON**. Change your `jigyasaCatList()` like this:

```
var jigyasaData = [Jigyasa_category_list]()

func jigyasaCatList(){
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!]
    print(params)
    Alamofire.request(apijigyasacategorylist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let jigyasaCategoryList = json["jigyasa_category_list"].arrayValue.map({ (data) -> Jigyasa_category_list in

                let jigyasa_english = data["jigyasa_english"].stringValue
                let jigyasa_hindi = data["jigyasa_hindi"].intValue
                let jigyasa_sanskrit = data["jigyasa_sanskrit"].stringValue

                let jigyasa = data["jigyasa"].arrayValue.map({ (jigyasa_data) -> Jigyasa in
                    let image3 = jigyasa_data["image3"].stringValue
                    let image1 = jigyasa_data["image1"].stringValue
                    let name_english = jigyasa_data["name_english"].intValue
                    let images = jigyasa_data["images"].stringValue
                    let name_hindi = jigyasa_data["name_hindi"].stringValue
                    let jigyasa_id = jigyasa_data["jigyasa_id"].stringValue
                    let image5 = jigyasa_data["image5"].stringValue
                    let image4 = jigyasa_data["image4"].stringValue
                    let name_sanskrit = jigyasa_data["name_sanskrit"].stringValue
                    let image2 = jigyasa_data["image2"].stringValue

                    return Jigyasa(image3: image3, image1: image1, name_english: name_english, images: images, name_hindi: name_hindi, jigyasa_id: jigyasa_id, image5: image5, image4: image4, name_sanskrit: name_sanskrit, image2: image2)
                })

                return Jigyasa_category_list(jigyasa_english: jigyasa_english, jigyasa_hindi: jigyasa_hindi, jigyasa_sanskrit: jigyasa_sanskrit, jigyasa: jigyasa)
            })

            if jigyasaCategoryList.count > 0 {
                self.jigyasaData = jigyasaCategoryList
            }

//            if data == []{
//
//            }else{
//                data.array?.forEach({ (jList) in
//                    let j_list = Jigyasa_category_list(jigyasa_english: jList["jigyasa_english"].stringValue, jigyasa_hindi: jList["jigyasa_hindi"].stringValue, jigyasa_sanskrit: jList["jigyasa_sanskrit"].stringValue, jigyasa: jList["jigyasa"].arrayObject as? [Jigyasa])
//                    self.jigyasaData.append(j_list)
//                })
//            }
            self.collView.reloadData()
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

To load an image from external resource like Api you can use **CocoaPods** like **KingFisher** or **SDWebImage**. Here I use **KingFisher**.

Follow the code below to show image in **UICollectionViewCell**.

```
struct CustomCellData {
    var title: String
    var image: String
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!

    var data: CustomCellData? {
        didSet {

            guard let data = data else {return}

            titleLabel.text = data.title

            let imageName = data.image.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

            cellImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            cellImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imageName), placeholder: nil, options: [
                .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                .transition(.fade(1)),
                .cacheOriginalImage
                ], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        cellImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to populate in collection view section wise ?

Comment: Does collectionView in tableViewCell has carousel behaviour?

Comment: collectionView has not carousel behaviour but has horizontal scroll

Comment: Please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154238/collectionview-with-the-horizontal-scroll-with-mulitple-section

Comment: yes i got it but issue is that images not set as per section

Comment: can you show some code how to display image in collectionView section wise

Comment: Where you want to display image? In UICollectionViewCell or in the section header of UITableView.

Comment: in collectionView cell and in response there is on field name `images` i want display that image in imageview which is inside uicollectionview cell

Comment: Okay i will check and let you know

Comment: so we don't need to use collectionView Delegate and datasource ?

Comment: Of course we need. Use collectionView Delegate and DataSource methods in your TableViewCell. Pass data to collectionViewCell in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` function. Use `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` function to set the number of item in collectionView.

Comment: Yes but i am not able to understand how `CustomCellData`  get data from json